# Why does an implementation of IntoIterator for a local type clash with the one in the core crate?

Tags: rust

I am able to implement `IntoIterator` for a custom type, but when the `IntoIterator` is bound to a custom trait, I cannot implement that trait.

The code below shows the issue.  When `IntoIterator` is implemented for a custom type (`FakeReader`), all works well.  However, when I try to implement `BmpReader` for that type, the compiler seems to pick up the internal `impl` of `IntoIterator` and requires that my custom type be an `Iterator`.

```rust
use core::iter::Iterator;

/// The trait that I'm designing
pub trait BmpReader : IntoIterator {
    const INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE: usize;
}

// Uncomment to see error
//impl BmpReader for FakeReader {
//     const INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 20;
//}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a FakeReader {
    type Item = &'a [u8];
    type IntoIter = FakeReaderIterator<'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Self::IntoIter{
            reader: &self,
            index: 0,
        }
    }
}

struct FakeReader {
    buffer: [u8; 20],
}

pub struct FakeReaderIterator<'a> {
    reader: &'a FakeReader,
    index: usize
}

impl<'a> Iterator for FakeReaderIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a [u8];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index == self.reader.buffer.len() {
            return None;
        }
        let result = &self.reader.buffer[self.index..self.index+1];
        self.index += 1;
        Some(result)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut reader = FakeReader {
        buffer: [0u8; 20]
    };
    let _= reader.buffer.iter_mut().enumerate().map(|(i,v)| *v = i as u8).count();
    for i in &reader {
        println!("{:?}", i)
    }
}
```

Uncommenting the problematic `impl` block results in this error:

```
error[E0277]: `FakeReader` is not an iterator
 --> src/main.rs:9:6
  |
9 | impl BmpReader for FakeReader {
  |      ^^^^^^^^^ `FakeReader` is not an iterator
  |
  = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `FakeReader`
  = help: the trait `IntoIterator` is implemented for `&'a FakeReader`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `FakeReader`
note: required by a bound in `BmpReader`
 --> src/main.rs:4:23
  |
4 | pub trait BmpReader : IntoIterator {
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `BmpReader`
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8f1a262caa71771c63014f1e3a5fd1ed)

Comment: your trait needs that the type implement IntoIterator, but you implemented it for `&FakeReader`, so `FakeReader` don't implement it.

Comment: looking through your code, implementing `IntoIterator` for `FakeReader` is going to be a mess. What you can do is bounding `&Self` to be `IntoIterator` for your trait: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b79a94f65df6b60bdcfbdc53ba2d8923)

Comment: @Bamontan `where for<'a> &'a Self: IntoIterator` is probably better.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm not totally familiar with the for syntax, I just did what I knew worked but thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Bamontan Thanks!  The suggested bound does indeed avoid triggering the error.  I'm not quite sure I understand why your suggestion works, but that's on me to figure it out.  If you want to make it an answer, I'll mark it as resolved.

Comment: @Bamontan BTW, the `where Self: 'a` bound [in the implementation of BmpReader](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/b79a94f65df6b60bdcfbdc53ba2d8923#file-playground-rs-L13) does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: @JavierCardona Yes you're right, I pluged that trying a to fix an error and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a trait with a trait bound, you are bounding `Self` to implement that trait, but in you case `&FakeReader` implement `IntoIterator`, so you can't implement `BmpReader` for `FakeReader` but you can for `&FakeReader`. You could write

```
impl<'a> BmpReader for &'a FakeReader {
    const INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 20;
}
```

Accessing the constant would mean to write

```
let size = <&FakeReader>::INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
```

and creating a fonction generic over `BmpReader`:

```
fn foo<T: BmpReader>(a: T) {
    let _size = T::INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
    let _iter = a.into_iter();
}

fn main() {
    let reader = FakeReader {
        buffer: [0u8; 20]
    };
    test(&reader);
}
```

The other solution is to bound `&Self` to implement `IntoIterator` for the trait:

```
pub trait BmpReader
    where for <'a> &'a Self: IntoIterator
{
    const INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE: usize;
}

impl BmpReader for FakeReader {
    const INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 20;
}
```

(the `for<'a> &'a Self: IntoIterator` is a suggestion of @Chayim Friedman)

you can now access the constant directly on `FakeReader`:

```
let size = FakeReader::INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
```

but creating a function generic over `BmpReader` needs you to specify the bound:

```
fn foo<T: BmpReader>(a: &T)
    where for <'a> &'a T: IntoIterator
{
    let _size = T::INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
    let _iter = a.into_iter();
}

fn main() {
    let reader = FakeReader {
        buffer: [0u8; 20]
    };
    foo(&reader);
}
```

Bot solutions are valid, choose which one suits your needs the most and makes the code the most readable/maintenable.